How to set backgroundColor of Elevated Button according to status?
I am working to builde a quiz game with flutter. I am new for flutter. In here that creates a four buttons for a question. It runs the checkAnswer method when press answer button and after it I want change backgroundColor for buttons. When I delete onPressed: result == null from button onPressed it change backgroundColor of buttons. But user can click button again again after one click. So when I added onPressed: result == null to prevent it, that don't update backgroundColor of buttons anymore. I don't understand whats the problem here. It's looking a silly problem.
...(currentQuestion["options"] as List<String>)
                          .map((option) =>
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                              // Alttan boşluk
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: result == null
                                    ? () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          selectedOption = option;
                                        });
                                        checkAnswer(option);
                                      }
                                    : null,
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    backgroundColor: result ==
                                                AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                                    ?.truth_answer &&
                                            selectedOption == option
                                        ? Colors.red
                                        : result ==
                                                    AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                                        ?.wrong_answer &&
                                                selectedOption == option
                                            ? Colors.blue
                                            : result ==
                                                        AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                                            ?.wrong_answer &&
                                                    currentQuestion["answer"]
                                                            as String ==
                                                        option
                                                ? Colors.red
                                                : Colors.blue),
                                child: Text(
                                  option,
                                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
                                ),
                              ))),

      void checkAnswer(String answer) {
        if (timer != null) {
          timer!.cancel();
        }
    
        setState(() {
          if (answer == questions[currentQuestionIndex]["answer"] as String) {
            result = AppLocalizations.of(context)?.truth_answer;
          } else {
            result = AppLocalizations.of(context)?.wrong_answer;
          }
    
          print("Seçilen seçenek: $selectedOption");
          print("Doğru cevap: ${questions[currentQuestionIndex]["answer"]}");
          print("Sonuç: $result");
        });
      }


After I searched lots of questions in stackoverflow I get the solution. I changed these parts of code:
ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    backgroundColor: result ==
                                                AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                                    ?.truth_answer &&
                                            selectedOption == option
                                        ? Colors.red
                                        : result ==
                                                    AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                                        ?.wrong_answer &&
                                                selectedOption == option
                                            ? Colors.blue
                                            : result ==
                                                        AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                                            ?.wrong_answer &&
                                                    currentQuestion["answer"]
                                                            as String ==
                                                        option
                                                ? Colors.red
                                                : Colors.blue),

with these code:
ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>((states) {
                                if (result == AppLocalizations.of(context)?.truth_answer && selectedOption == option) {
                                  return Colors.green;
                                } else if (result == AppLocalizations.of(context)?.wrong_answer && selectedOption == option) {
                                  return Colors.blue;
                                } else if (result == AppLocalizations.of(context)?.wrong_answer && currentQuestion["answer"] as String == option) {
                                  return Colors.green;
                                } else {
                                  return Colors.blue.shade200;
                                }
                              }),
                            ),

